Vuetify date-picker changing weekday labels from S M T W T F S => Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
I have a problem with weekday labels, I cannot find a way to change them to this format
(from M to Mon etc...)
my code :
 <v-date-picker
     :weekday-format="customWeekDays"
     v-model="selectedDate"
     show-adjacent-months
 ></v-date-picker>

and
const customWeekDays = computed(() => {
  return ['Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa', 'Su'];
});

const selectedDate = ref<Date[] | undefined>(undefined);

const selectedDateDisplay = computed(() => {
  if (selectedDate.value instanceof Date) {
    return format(selectedDate.value, 'dd MMM yyyy');
  }
  return '';
});

I have tried this   :weekday-format from (How to change day-format (M > Mo, F > Fr...) in Date/month pickers of Vuetify) prop but it doesnt seem to work for me

VDatePicker uses getWeekdays() from the date adapter to print the week day labels (see code). The default implementation can be found here.
You can switch out the adapter for a different one, as described in the docs.
Here is a playground example with an overridden getWeekdays() (check the vuetify.js tab - I'm using @date-fns/luxon adapter because it is easy to get into the playground, you could just as easy override the default adapter or pick a different one in your project).
Probably not as straight-forward as you were hoping for, but there it is. Hope it helps.

Thank you, that is exactly what I wanted, appreciate you man :D
